# SharePoint Online Calendar Web part issue in Safari

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I created a calendar web part on a site page in SharePoint online using IE. One of the users has a Mac, and uses Safari on it. Now this calendar loads as empty with no events every time he accesses the page, it also does nothing when trying to navigate to the next month. If I use safari on windows I get the same issue as well. Oddly if I click "Edit Page", the calendar events load. So it is clearly capable, but just refuses to do so. I've researched into this and found various issues with Safari and SharePoint, but not this particular one.

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: did you add this webpart in a Rich Text content area of the site page?

Comment: @sekhar I just added it in the usual manner, by using the "app part" ribbon option and selecting calendar. As to whether this is default part of a rich text content area I am unsure.

Comment: Ok, I faced the similar issue when I added into a Rich Text area. I moved it to a different webpart zone, and it started working. I've faced similar issues with other OOTB webparts(ex:Search results). I was getting a JS error when I added a Search results webpart in Site Page. I moved everything to   a publishing page and everything started working fine. No JS errors in console. Check if you are getting any console errors in yoour browser. If yes move the webpart out of RTE zone. if that doesn't solve the issue, go for a publishing page instead of a site page.

Comment: @sekhar Moving it into a new WebPart page has worked for me, convert your comment as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebParts added into Rich text zone causes JavaScript issues in Site Pages. They get executed before the dependent scripts loaded (like sp.js using SOD). So move the WebPart to a non Rich text WebPartZone. If that doesn't work, use a publishing page instead.

Comment: How do you create a non rich text webpartzone? I haven't been able to find that out.