# Calendar not showing in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

Using SharePoint 2013 (Office Online 365) and added a team calendar to front page, which has overlays.

The calendar works and shows all events in Internet Explorer 11. Now if I use another browser like Firefox (latest build) and Google Chrome (latest build) it simply doesnt work.

I have used the developer options for the both browsers to debug the issue and all I can come up with is this below.

> Type Error: A is Null
>
> sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js

I have no idea if this is casuing an issue here nor no idea what it means, but thats all I can find.

Now to throw a spanner in the works here, in Firefox or Chrome if I edit the page **ALL** the calendar invites show up and it works perfect. If I save the page they disapear.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint JavaScript is weak. There are so many bad and incoherent decisions in the code base, that I can't see getting fixed without a complete rewrite. Including all the old web parts. This kinda points ASP.NET 5/MVC6 gun at SharePoint. Can't see SharePoint survive that one :)

The problem here stems from the web parts complex DOM structure and how Chrome interprets this differently. You can fix it by hi-jacking the function that fails and wrap it in a try/catch.

This fix will have no negative consequence towards other code, as SharePoint JS code doesn't use try/catch. Only thing that might happen is that the generated function name $6d_2 can change with the next build, so the fix is as brittle as SharePoint itself, but still better than nothing. 
For SharePoint 2016 (OnPrem) this has to be $6f_2

Just put this in a Script Editor web part on the same page as the Calendar overlay webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var oldFunc = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarTableBase.prototype.$6d_2;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarTableBase.prototype.$6d_2 = function(){
      try{
        oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      catch(err){
          console.log('SharePoint Calendar web part just crashed! Ignoring');
          console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
  }, "sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js");
}());

</script>
```

Comment: +1 "For SharePoint 2016 (OnPrem) this has to be $6f_2"

Answer (score 4):

I've been having this same issue for the past two weeks and searched through ton's of blogs and forums before coming across [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156502/sharepoint-online-calendar-web-part-issue-in-safari) post.

If you don't want to read that whole thread, the short answer is the Calendar Web Part was added in a Rich Text Zone. This causes the JavaScript error you were getting that kept the Calendar Overlays from displaying and the Calendar from being responsive.

I moved my Calendar into the header section and all of the overlays are now showing correctly. You can move the Calendar to any non-Rich Text Web Part Zone, or use a publishing page instead.

Let me know if that works!