# SharePoint Online Calendar Web part only shows events when in Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar web part on a site that should show the absence of colleagues, however, on the page none of the entered absences is shown.

When I click Edit in the top right corner to view the page with the calendar in Edit Mode the absences are filled out. Also, in normal view I can't switch between months, add events, ... While in Edit Mode this is possible.

[image: Edit Button]

I have already tried deleting the web part and recreating it (both on the same site as on another) but the issue still continues. Does anyone know why this happens and, if so, how I could resolve this?

I added screenshots of the calendar below, at the bottom of the message.

If there is any other information you need or you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks in advance!

[image: Calendar - Normal View]
[image: Calendar - Edit Mode]

EDIT 1

---

Screenshot of the console in normal view, in Edit mode the error isn't there:

[image: Console]

I have also noticed, thanks to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156502/sharepoint-online-calendar-web-part-issue-in-safari), that on IE this issue does not occur, but I would like for it to work in Chrome as well but I don't know how to create a new Web Part Zone and I can't find any documentation that shows how to do this without SP Designer. I don't have SP Designer available so if it's possible to create one without it please elaborate on how I would be able to achieve this. If it's necessary to have SP Designer, how do I figure out which version to install? (This part of the question will be removed after I know the answer because it's not relevant to the issue described in the title)

Comment: are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I see this JS error in my console when not in edit mode:  `$6d_2 — sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js:2:100383T ypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.offsetWidth')`

Comment: I think its relating to the same issue experience here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156502/sharepoint-online-calendar-web-part-issue-in-safari?rq=1, except I'm not sure how to implement what they are talking about.

Comment: @tomsmithweb I added a screenshot of the error in the question, the error is gone when I enter Edit Mode

Comment: @mdance thank you for the reference, I didn't find that question myself.. It seems that IE does work as it should, but the issue occurs in chrome.

Comment: I can confirm it works in IE. The issue is due to a JavaScript bug in browsers that use the WebKit JavaScript engine. So Chrome and Safari will break on it. I have yet to confirm Firefox.